# How to implement a round shape UI in Android

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I am working on a android project where i have to implement UI like below.
where center image is an product image, surrounded with a three buttons. On click of that it is going to redirect to some other screen.

Is there any one who did this before? Your prompt reply will be really appreciated thanks.

[image]

Comment: You can use some picture to achieved it. When click on coordinate of a button, change background picture.

Comment: did u have any idea how to get that coordinate..

Comment: Use `OnTouchListener` to listen whenever user touch on this view, and use `MotionEvent` to get coordinate.

Comment: What about something like [this](https://github.com/szugyi/Android-CircleMenu)?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **FrameLayout**. 
Image that this UI is composed of 4 same size components, which overlapped with the transparent part.
Then you should make some filtering operations in **onTouchEvent**  to avoid the confused clicking event, because once you click the component, the other components will wait to respond.

There are two way to filter.

1. Linear Programming in the math way
2. Judged by the color of pixel

Obviously, the second is a better choice. So, you can use **getPixel(x, y)**,  which belongs to the **Bitmap**, to get the color value at the specified coordinate. If it is a transparent color, then **return false** to pass the touch event to the next layer View or **return true** to intercept it.

After that you will get the correct clicking event in your own **OnClickListener**.